# Springboot: PathVariable validation where the condition {variable}.isBlank/{variable}.isEmpty not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am having one controller where I want to validate the PathVariable where it cannot be null. For example, http://localhost:8080/api/details/expired-timeoff/ where I want to validate the path variable behind '/' in this path.

I have my controller here where I want to throw my Exception with error message on it.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping("/api/details")
public class DetailsController {
    @Autowired
    DetailsService detailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    OvertimeService overtimeService;
        
    // TESTING HERE!!!!
    @GetMapping("/expired-timeoff/{empNo}")
    public List<Details> getExpiredTimeOffBalancesByUser(@PathVariable String empNo) {

        if (empNo.isBlank() || empNo.isEmpty() || empNo.trim().equals("a")) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error Message");
        }
        return detailsService.findExpiredTimeOffBalancesByCreatedBy(empNo);
    }


}
```

Meanwhile, when I GET from "http://localhost:8080/api/details/expired-timeoff/a", I am able enter the condition and catch my InvalidArgumentException message
[Successfully catch my exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fb39.png)

and when I GET from  "http://localhost:8080/api/details/expired-timeoff/", it will just return me the default Whitelabel 404 error
[Exception not catched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkFaE.png)

I did some research on it and it is stated that the PathVariable cannot be null, but what can I do to prompt the InvalidArgumentException if the user accidentally make the path variable "null"?

Here's my @RestControllerAdvise file

```
package com.sicmsb.timeofftracker.controller.Advice;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;

import com.sicmsb.timeofftracker.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.sicmsb.timeofftracker.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class RequestExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) //404
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public String notFound(Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) //500
    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class, Exception.class})
    public String internalError(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error/internal_error";
    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) //400
    @ExceptionHandler({InvalidArgumentException.class})
    public String badRequest(Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

UPDATE : It seems like I can handle the error like this. Is there any way that I can just stick to one function to handle all of it? Tried String.utils(empNo) and empNo==null, still not going in the condition.

```
// Handles cases where empNo is NOT provided
@GetMapping("/expired-timeoff/")
public List<Details> getExpiredTimeOffBalancesByUser() {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error Message2");
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ooops, I'm the one responsible for the Community feedback "Please provide enough code ...". Hello Wilson, welcome on stackoverflow. You can ignore the Community Bot comment above. What I  meant was: rather than including images (or links to images) of the browser, include the messages themselves in plain text. The link will eventually be gone in the future, and the information contained in it with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```java
 @GetMapping({"/expired-timeoff/", "/expired-timeoff/{empNo}"})
 public List<Details> getExpiredTimeOffBalancesByUser(@PathVariable(required=false) String empNo) {
   // test if empNo is null
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more condition in IF statement to check empNo is null or not.

```
if (empNo == null || empNo.isBlank() || empNo.isEmpty() || empNo.trim().equals("a"))
{
throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error Message");
}
```

Comment: It's still the same with empNo==null, didn't go into the condition either 

Comment: Better write your business logic in try/catch block so that while debugging you will get to know about issue.
also check datatype of your pathvariable.